# postgresql jsonb find key in object

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

I have a JSON object that could look like the following:

```
{
    "key1" : "value1",
    "key2" : {
        "messagebody" : {
            "version" : "1"
        },
        "messageheader" : {
            "reference" : "a reference"
        }
    }
}
```

This is stored in a `PostgeSQL` table in a column with type `jsonb`. My goal is now to find the field `version` and the field `reference`. But the structure of the json could vary, so eg. `key2` could be named `key3` in another record.

Is there a query in PostgreSQL that allow's me to give it a key and find the value of that key in the object no mather where in the object it is located?

The PostgreSQL version is 10.

Comment: Which Postgres version are you using?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name using version 10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Postgres 10 use a recursive query.

```
with recursive extract_all as
(
    select 
        key,
        value
    from my_table
    cross join lateral jsonb_each(jdata)
union all
    select
        obj_key,
        obj_value
    from extract_all
    left join lateral 
        jsonb_each(value) 
        as o(obj_key, obj_value) 
        on jsonb_typeof(value) = 'object'
    where obj_key is not null
)
select *
from extract_all
where key in ('version', 'reference')
```

Postgres 12+ allows an alternative solution with SQL/JSON Path.

```
select
    'version' as key,
    jsonb_path_query(jdata, '$.**.version') as value
from my_table
union all
select
    'reference' as key,
    jsonb_path_query(jdata, '$.**.reference') as value
from my_table
```

[Db<>fidlle.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=9285c27d18e7a1f69b4d46563585592f)